# Boolean Expression as Named Variables

Tags: python, pandas

For readability purposes, I am trying to use named variables in my boolean expressions. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Here is an example of my code:

```
employee     = ((df.EmpStat == 1) & (df.COW in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

I will put this into a series of `if..elif..else` statements.

I have also tried to utilize what the error message is telling me through the following code:

```
employee     = ((df.EmpStat == 1) & (df.COW in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])).all() [along with the other expressions any() etc...]
```

Comment: use `and` instead of `&`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Nope, the error here is the use of `in` `&` is the correct operator to use when working with arrays

Comment: Also, forgot to mention I am working with a Pandas dataframe, which `&` is used instead of `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
employee     = ((df.EmpStat == 1) & (df.COW.isin([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
```

the `in` is a problem here as it won't work with array like structures as you expect, using [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) allows you to produce a mask for matches in the passed in list of values

Example:

```
In [52]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmpStat':[0,0,1,1,1,0], 'COW':np.arange(3,9)})
df

Out[52]:
   COW  EmpStat
0    3        0
1    4        0
2    5        1
3    6        1
4    7        1
5    8        0
```

Now produce a mask and use it to mask your df:

```
In [53]:    
employee = ((df.EmpStat == 1) & (df.COW.isin([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])))
df[employee]

Out[53]:
   COW  EmpStat
2    5        1
```

The mask can be shown to be a boolean array:

```
In [54]:
employee

Out[54]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

If we try to use just `in` you get the error:

```
In [55]:
df.COW in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-3c7e485c5e38> in <module>()
----> 1 df.COW in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.1\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
    712         raise ValueError("The truth value of a {0} is ambiguous. "
    713                          "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
--> 714                          .format(self.__class__.__name__))
    715 
    716     __bool__ = __nonzero__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```